# Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.1 Ignoring bootsnap-1.3.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.1

Tags: linux, terminal, ruby-on-rails-5

rails generate acts_as_votable:migration
Ignoring bootsnap-1.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.1
Ignoring bootsnap-1.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.1
/home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:491:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:466:in`validate_runtime!'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in`'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in`'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/server.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/server.rb:9:in`call'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`run'
    from /home/ayesha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `'

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what to do, though perhaps not very directly.

Try running this command:

```
gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.3.1
```

That will try to reinstall the `bootsnap` gem from scratch.